# SIGTERM not trapped by AWS ECS docker container

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I have the following ECS container definition

```
ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: myfluentd
          Essential: true
          Image: !Ref DockerImage
          MountPoints:
            - SourceVolume: efs-volume
              ContainerPath: '/fluentd/buffers'
              ReadOnly: false
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 24224
              HostPort: 24224
              Protocol: tcp
          EntryPoint:
            - "/var/lib/twistlock/defender.sh"
            - "defender"
            - "entrypoint"
            - "tini"
            - "--"
            - "/bin/entrypoint.sh"
          Command:
            - fluentd
          VolumesFrom:
            - ReadOnly: false
              SourceContainer: "TwistlockDefender"
```

The `ENTRYPOINT` is

`["/var/lib/twistlock/fargate/fargate_defender.sh","fargate","entrypoint","tini","--","/bin/entrypoint.sh"]`

and the contents of `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

#source vars if file exists
DEFAULT=/etc/default/fluentd

if [ -r $DEFAULT ]; then
    set -o allexport
    . $DEFAULT
    set +o allexport
fi

# If the user has supplied only arguments append them to `fluentd` command
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- fluentd "$@"
fi

# If user does not supply config file or plugins, use the default
if [ "$1" = "fluentd" ]; then
    if ! echo $@ | grep ' \-c' ; then
       set -- "$@" -c /fluentd/etc/${FLUENTD_CONF}
    fi

    if ! echo $@ | grep ' \-p' ; then
       set -- "$@" -p /fluentd/plugins
    fi
fi

. /bin/env.sh

task_cleanup() {
    echo "Deleting files"
    rm -rf /tmp/*
    exit
}
trap task_cleanup SIGTERM SIGINT

exec "$@"
```

When I stop a ECS task it issues the `SIGTERM` to the container and I expect it to executed the `task_cleanup()`, however the signal is not caught.

I logged into the container to check the processes

```
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 fluent    0:00 sh /var/lib/twistlock/defender.sh defender entrypoint tini -- /bin/entrypoint.sh fluentd
    7 fluent    0:00 /var/lib/twistlock/defender defender entrypoint tini -- /bin/entrypoint.sh fluentd
   16 root      0:00 /managed-agents/execute-command/amazon-ssm-agent
   22 fluent    0:00 /sbin/tini -- /bin/entrypoint.sh fluentd
   29 fluent    0:02 {fluentd} /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf -p /fluentd/plugins
   72 root      0:00 /managed-agents/execute-command/ssm-agent-worker
   90 fluent    1:06 /usr/bin/ruby -Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit /usr/bin/fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf -p /fluentd/plugins --under-supervisor
  546 root      0:00 /managed-agents/execute-command/ssm-session-worker ecs-execute-command-03931001c6df08625
  556 root      0:00 /bin/bash
  870 root      0:00 ps aux
```

What am I missing? why is the signal not getting trapped?

UPDATE: The `ENTRYPOINT` kicks off 2 containers and I think the signal is only sent to the first container - when I removed the first container, I was able to see the cleanup working. Any thoughts how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the POSIX documentation for `exec`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec) (bolding mine):

> If exec is specified with `command`, it shall **replace the shell with `command`** without creating a new process. ...

Your shell process and the signal handler you created with `trap` no longer exists once you call `exec "$@"`.

This will probably do what you want, but it's totally untested and I haven't analyzed what the string `"$@"` that you've constructed:

```
   .
   .
   .
task_cleanup() {
    echo "Deleting files"
    rm -rf /tmp/*
}
trap task_cleanup SIGTERM SIGINT

# background the task
"$@" &
pid=$!

wait $pid

kill $pid

exit
```

Instead of *replacing* the shell with the command held in `"$@"`, this would run the command as a child process of the shell.

Comment: I'm sorry - this did not work as well. It did not delete the directory/file.

Comment: @fledgling Did it call your `task_cleanup()` function?

Comment: no it did not call the task_cleanup()

Comment: Any other thoughts to get this working?

Comment: @fledgling Per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614780/why-is-the-wait-pid-command-interrupted-by-any-signal-to-the-waiting-process, I've updated this answer.

Comment: I think the problem here is the SIGNAL is routed to the first child process which is `/var/lib/twistlock/defender.sh defender entrypoint` and not `tini -- /bin/entrypoint.sh fluentd`. When I removed the `/var/lib/twistlock/defender.sh defender entrypoint` it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Save following script in `test.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
task_cleanup() {
    echo "Deleting files"
}
trap task_cleanup SIGTERM

"$@"
```

and run it with :

```
bash test.sh sleep 60
```

Now run `ps -ef|grep "bash test.sh sleep 60"` (in another bash session) to grab the PID, then run

```
kill -TERM PID
```

The process will catch the signal TERM but only run `task_cleanup` AFTER `sleep 60` finishes.